# Highstock date input, page jumps to top on ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

In highstock on the ipad if you have content before the chart and you have to scroll down the page to view the chart, clicking on the date input jumps the page to the top and you can't see the chart, see http://jsbin.com/oyicuc/35

Also, the keyboard opens by default, we're using the jquery ui datepicker in our project and so ideally we would like the keyboard not to open, is this possible? Even better would to be able to use the native iOS datepicker. Don't really want to have to write our own function with custom inputs...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably the same issue as https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1645, which will be fixed with the next maintenance.